# Python -Method to calculate slopes by rolling regression

Tags: python, regression, nan

Is there any method to calculate slopes by rolling(window=5) regression?

```
df
              A   
2016-01-01  5.9 
2016-01-02  6.3 
2016-01-03  NaN 
2016-01-04  5.6 
2016-01-05  4.3
2016-01-06  5.6
2016-01-07  4.6
2016-01-08  4.0
2016-01-09  7.0
...

result
              A   
2016-01-01  - 
2016-01-02  - 
2016-01-03  - 
2016-01-04  - 
2016-01-05  NaN
2016-01-06  NaN
2016-01-07  NaN
2016-01-08  xxx 
2016-01-09  xxx
...
#(xxx stands for some value)
```

I tried to calculate values using linregress, but it didn't work with this frame including NaN.

Just ignore Nan if there's some in the window.

```
from scipy.stats import linregress
df.apply(lambda v: linregress(df.index, df.A)[0])
```